# Error when installing modules drupal6.2

Tags: drupal

i am very new to drupal ,when i was tring to install the modules i am facing these errors.can any one suggest how to deal with this?

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in      C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\views.module on line 879.  
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in     C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter.inc on line 589.  
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_submit() should be compatible with views_handler::options_submit($form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter.inc on line 589.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_boolean_operator::value_validate() should be compatible with views_handler_filter::value_validate($form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter_boolean_operator.inc on line 149.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_validate() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_validate(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_row.inc on line 135.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_row.inc on line 135.
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views\views.module on line 879.
```

Comment: which drupal version you are using? consider latest stable release 7.22. And please name modules as well which are causing problem?

Comment: i am using drupal 6.2.the website  i am trying to run works the best on 6.2.Can you tell me the above warning is all about.

Comment: IN php you can't disable strict warning. see a solution here : http://groups.drupal.org/node/217529#comment-826138 . Next do some research first before posting.

Comment: Thanks akshayb.But is this a serious warning to prevent from running?

Comment: I think this should be moved to drupal stack exchange site. Any moderators agree?

Comment: Hacking core is hardly a great solution but it does the trick, and I don't have this issue in production, only dev.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to run Drupal 6.2 on PHP 5.4. For Drupal 6 the recommended version of PHP is 5.2. Anything above that there is no guarantee that there would not be errors but it might run without errors in 5.3 based on modules you have set up on your site.

See https://drupal.org/requirements